# Python oneline foreach verification in string

Tags: python

I want to be sure that none item of a list is present on a string.

At the moment I do :

```
presents = False
for item in item_list:
    if item in string_control:
        presents = True
        break;
```

Is there a way to do it in only one line ? I really often do these types of control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes :

```
presents = any(x in string_control for x in item_list)
```

Comment: Awesome response. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

I think `string_control` has a value something like this. `presents` then becomes a boolean indicating the same as in your code but most likely in most circumstances you don't need the cast to bool. I.e. this probably works fine too: `presents = [i for i in item_list if i == string_control]`

```
string_control = None
presents = bool([i for i in item_list if i == string_control])
```

Comment: I think string_control is a list, not None